# How do I prove that this map has even degree?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I have the following problem:

> Show that if $f:C\rightarrow C'$ is a map between circles s.t. $f(P^*)=f(P)$ forall $P$ then the degree is even. (Remark $P^*$ is the antipodal point of $P$)

My Idea was the following.

W.l.o.g. one can take $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ s.t. $f(P^*)=f(P)$ forall $P$. To be more precise in this case we have that $P^*=-P$ so the condition can be rewritten as $f(-P)=f(P)$. Now let us define $$g:S^1\rightarrow S^1;\,\,\,z\mapsto f(\sqrt{z})$$ and $$\phi:S^1\rightarrow S^1;\,\,\,P\mapsto P^2$$ Then clearly $g(\phi(P))=f(P)$ and therefore also $deg(f)=deg(g)\cdot deg(\phi)$ but now we know that $deg(\phi)=2$ and therefore $$deg(f)=deg(g)\cdot deg(\phi)=2\cdot deg(g)$$.

I'm not sure if this works because I somehow never used explicitly that $f(-P)=f(P)$, therefore I wanted to ask if this is correct or not?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to take care on how to choose the square root. Probably the fact that you can construct $g$ is that $f(-P)=f(P)$

Comment: okei I see your point. I also think that so $g$ don't make much sence since $\sqrt{(x,y)}$ is not defined. But component wise wouldn't work either. Do you have a hint

Comment: Ok so think of the antipodal map $g : \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb S^1$. Your equation says that $f=f\circ g$. What does that say about the degree of your map?

Comment: so by antipodal map you mean the map $z\mapsto z^*=-z$ right? If we know that $f=f\circ g$ we can compute the degree by $deg(f)=deg(f)\cdot deg(g)$. Right? but then we still need the degree of $g$ but we had a proposition saying that the degree of the antipodal map from a circle to itself is $1$ then this wouldn't help us or where did I made a mistake?

Comment: The condition on $f$ implies that it factors through the quotient map $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^1$.  What is the degree of this map?

Comment: but why did @AitorIribarLopez give me the hint with the antipodal map?